# Google analytics advertiser features policy

Tags: google-analytics

I am interested in using the demographics and interest reporting in Google Analytics. I have turned on the `Enable Demographics and Interest Reports` option in the property settings for one of my domains. There is a note there that says I may need to turn on `advertiser features` for this to work. I haven't turned on the advertiser features yet because there is another note there that says:

```
"You may need to update your privacy policy before enabling Advertiser Features."
```

I'm curious if anyone has worked extensively with `advertiser features` before and what type of language needs to be used in updating the privacy policy, if any?

Comment: I went through this a while ago and admittedly, I cannot remember much detail, however, I do seem to remember that Google did list what elements needed to exist in the privacy policy and these elements would be the same for any privacy policy you would write that includes Adsense. For myself, I simply mentioned that the Adsense and GA products are being used and the privacy policy of Google applies and supplied a link(s) if a user wants to know more. If you cover these elements, I am pretty sure you are safe enough. Google is just covering it's bases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of [policy requirements](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2700409?hl=en) for Google Analytics Advertiser Features.

The policy states:

> If you've enabled any Google Analytics Display features, you are
> required to notify your visitors by disclosing the following
> information in your privacy policy:
>
> The Google Analytics Advertising Features you've implemented.
>
> How you
> and third-party vendors use first-party cookies (such as the Google
> Analytics cookie) or other first-party identifiers, and third-party
> cookies (such as the DoubleClick cookie) or other third-party
> identifiers together.
>
> How visitors can opt-out of the Google Analytics
> Advertiser Features you use, including through Ads Settings, Ad
> Settings for mobile apps, or any other available means (for example,
> the NAI's consumer opt-out).

They also encourage you to link to their [opt-outs](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout/).